# powershell cannot run a command from "Run as" box

Tags: powershell

I have a one liner that I run from the windows run command :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\casper\PuTTY\putty.exe" -ssh "192.168.1.2" -l casper -pw "<password>" -m \\PROD.MSAD.casp.NET\UserData\CASPER\Home\Documents\pbauth_list.txt -t
```

It works great. 
However I tried copying the one liner to a .ps1 file like this:

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\casper\PuTTY\putty.exe" -ssh "192.168.1.2" -l casper -pw "<password>" -m \\PROD.MSAD.casp.NET\UserData\CASPER\Home\Documents\pbauth_list.txt -t
```

Running it from powershell and I get his error

```
 The system cannot find the file -ssh
```

Saved this as a .bat and tried to open in thorough powershell

I get a message box

```
Windows cannot find '-ssh'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again
```

I have tried all types of permutations with escaping the quotes, quoting the whole line. Can't get it to work as a saved command but it works great from the run as box. The same command worked fine from the run dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `start`, you should be using `& "C:\Program Files (x86)\casper\PuTTY\putty.exe" <rest of args>`

Answer (score 0):

I would run the command like this.

```
Start-Process "C:\Program Files (x86)\casper\PuTTY\putty.exe" -Argumentlist  "-ssh", "192.168.1.2", "-l", "casper", "-pw", "<password>", "-m", "\\PROD.MSAD.casp.NET\UserData\CASPER\Home\Documents\pbauth_list.txt", "-t"
```

This to make sure that arguments are sent to the putty command and not to the start command which is your issue.